# Is it possible to add containers programmatically to a pageview list in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter

i wanted my list of pageview containers to be created according to the number of documents in a collection in my cloud Firestore so that when clicked i can display data from each document on each page, is there a way to do this,thanks

Comment: Check out [ask] to improve this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `StreamBuilder` with a `PageView.builder` inside as the builder. For example, let `Object` be the type of the documents you are getting from Firestore:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: StreamBuilder<List<Object>>(
              stream: firestoreService.getObjectsList, // something that returns an Object
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.data == null) {
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                } else {
                  return Scrollbar(
                    child: PageView.builder(
                        itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          // return something for each object in each page
                        }),
                  );
                }
              }),
        ));
  }
```